# Delete cache files and free allocated memory for it programmatically

Tags: javascript, performance, caching, browser-cache, samsung-smart-tv

I am building an app for SmartTV which is mainly (JavaScript & HTML5). The application is very slow due to the RAM size on the TV and the processor speed.

I am working currently to solve this issue. I have decided to delete the cache file whenever a new page loads, and the user moves to another page.

Is this solution going to help with the (RAM & CPU) problem? And how can delete them programmatically?

I have tried the following code :

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Will this code set the cache file size to ZERO after I call it in the page?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not. This code tell browser not to cache page. It will apply only to html page. And will not affect any resources loaded on this page.